# Screen capture with AppleScript

Tags: safari, applescript, screenshot, keystroke

Working on a AppleScript that opens a webpage in Safari and makes a screen capture of a specific area (using Cmd+Shift+4). But I'm having trouble making the screen capture part automatic.

I'm using MouseTools to click and move the mouse around.

```
set x to POSIX file ((POSIX path of (path to me)) & "/.." & "/MouseTools") as text
set pathName to POSIX path of x

tell application "Safari" to activate
open location "http://google.com"
delay 1
#do shell script quoted form of pathName & " -x 500 -y 167"
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    #keystroke "3" using {command down, shift down}
end tell
delay 1
#do shell script quoted form of pathName & " -leftClick"
```

etc...

The keystroke command is working for everything BUT the screen capture. Next problem is moving the mouse while holding leftclick down. Has somebody got this to work or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm happy to see you're using [MouseTools](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html). That's my program! However there is a command line tool to take screen shots called screencapture. I'm sure you should be using that instead of your gui approach. For example, here's how to get a picture of your whole desktop...

```
set imagePath to (path to desktop as text) & "screenCapture.png"
do shell script "screencapture -mx -T0 " & quoted form of POSIX path of imagePath
```

I'm sure there's ways to capture just a certain area of the screen using screencapture. A little searching of its man page or google should turn up something on that.

Comment: It's a nice little command line tool you made there. I tested out the screencapture command tool and it works fine for screenshots of the full screen. Unfortunately it doesnt work in combination with your MouseTools. When I use `do shell script "screencapture -i ~/Desktop/picture.png"` (same as CMD+SHIFT+4) it stays in that mode till I manually click the mouse, and it wont respond to `do shell script quoted form of pathName & " -leftClick"` or anything from other scripts.

Comment: That's too bad screencapture can't do just portions of the screen and doesn't recognize MouseTools clicks. However another idea would be to take a full screen shot and then use another tool to crop the image of the full screen to the size you need. Image events can only crop at the center of the image but you could use a tool like ImageMagick to crop wherever you need. See here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Comment: A simple task seem to evolve into a giant script with several different programs popping up. Think I have to rethink my strategy. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Buy why is it that the most obvious approach using the GUI command key sequences does not work?